# TFS - deployment group servers run same test

Tags: tfs

I am using visual studio test runner task inside the deployment group phase in the release definition. I defined test assemblies to run but all the agents run the exact same tests in parallel. What have i missed in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you specified the same test assemblies on all agents, then of course they will run the same tests.

If you want to speed up the Test Execution, then you need to distribute runs to multiple machines.

Please refer to below articles for parallel testing:

- [Parallel Test Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/10/10/parallel-test-execution/)
- [Speeding up Unit Test Execution in TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/07/30/speeding-up-unit-test-execution-in-tfs/)
- [Running Unit Tests on different machine during TFS 2015 build](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/06/04/running-unit-tests-on-different-machine-during-tfs-2015-build/)
- [Enable parallel execution of tests using the Visual Studio Test
  Runner 2015.1](https://jessehouwing.net/vstest-enable-parallel-execution/)